# make JavaScript script src appear local

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript file that points to another website as the source:

`<script src="https://example.com/requiredcode.js" async></script>`

This script element is going to be sent to my clients and they are going to place it manually on their websites. And I would prefer that it at least looks like the code is going through my website domain.

I want it to look like this:

`<script src="https://mywebsite.com/script.js" async></script>`

This is simply an aesthetic issue.

I don't care if clients go into the code itself and see that it relies on 3rd parties. I just don't want the main `<script>` element to look like it's relying on a 3rd party itself.

UPDATE:

I thought of hosting the file locally on my website. But the problem is that the 3rd party file is sometimes manually updated by the 3rd party.

Comment: "*What are the best ways to accomplish this?*" Why not just host the file on your domain as you would normally? "*I just don't want the main `<script>` element to look like it's relying on a 3rd party itself.*" For my curiosity, if you would, can you elaborate on why this is a bad thing?

Comment: "This script element is going to be sent to my clients. And I would prefer that it at least looks like the code is going through my website domain."

How are you serving this script element? How do clients request this script element?

Comment: I thought of hosting the code on my own website. But sometimes it's manually updated by the 3rd party source.

Comment: Getting a bit tangential, but I feel this is important to bring up: "*But sometimes it's manually updated by the 3rd party source.*" Why introduce a potential failure point when it's not necessary? What happens if in the future the registration for your "website domain" lapses and your clients' sites break as a result? What about if you want to reconfigure your server and you do so in a manner which stops resolving the script the same way? For these reasons among several others I would recommend re-thinking this design.

Comment: Hey Esqew, great question. The reason I don't want to link to 3rd party directly is because I'm making sure clients are reliant on my services for functionality.

Comment: @SethConnell Ethical implications aside (of which I think there are many when (ostensibly) charging for something that amounts to the proxying of an otherwise freely-available service like `cdnjs`, especially without adding any value), what you're probably looking for is to set up a server (an API, perhaps) that simply performs the request from your server to the third party's server and returns the response back to the client.

Comment: @esqew, I'm just trying to avoid making my system seem like a patchwork of different tools when I can make it all look like it falls under one umbrella. As far as APIs go, is there a way to do this that doesn't require an API solution?

Comment: If the third party service you're mentioning supports the use of custom domains, you could work with the third party to set up a subdomain off your apex with a `CNAME`, pointing back to the CDN itself. Even without their buy-in you could hypothetically still do this, but things will break when the SSL verification fails.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231950/discussion-between-seth-connell-and-esqew).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have your HTML link to a .js file on your website that then loads in the third party library like this:

HTML:

```
<script src="https://mywebsite.com/script.js" async></script>
```

JS:

```
function headScript(url_check, fn) {
  if (typeof url_check != 'object') {
    url_check = [url_check]
  }
  var url = url_check[0]
  var checkFor = url_check[1]
  if (!window[checkFor]) {

    var script = document.createElement('script')
    document.head.appendChild(script)

    script.onload = fn
    return (script.src = url)
  }
  fn && fn()
}

headScript('https://example.com/requiredcode.js', function() {
  // run when file is loaded
})
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!